# Request npm: Handling Redirects

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, npm

I was wondering if anyone knew how to handle redirects with the Request npm from sites such as bitly or tribal or Twitter's t.co URLs. For example, if I have web page that I want to scrape with the Request npm and the link I have to get to that page is a bity or shortened URL that is going to redirect me, how do I handle those redirects?

I found that the Request npm has a "followRedirect" options set to true by default. If I set that to false I can get the next link that the page will redirect me to by scraping that page that is returned, but that isn't the best because I don't know how many redirects I am going to have to go through.

Right now I am getting a 500 error. When I have "followRedirect" set to true. When I have "followRedirect" set to false, I can get each redirect page. Again, I don't know how many redirect pages I will have to go through. Code is below:

```
var options = {
  followRedirect: false
};

request('http://t.co/gJ74UfmH4i', options, function(err, response, body){
     // when options are set I get the redirect page
     // when options are not set I get a 500
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the NodeJS package called Request by Mikael (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, you need to get the last redirect url, using followAllRedirects: true parameter

```
request('http://t.co/gJ74UfmH4i', {
  method: 'HEAD',
  followAllRedirects: true
}, function(err, response, body) {
  var url = response.request.href
})
```

>

The second part is making request to final url, with some browser-like headers

```
request(url, {
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.46 Safari/537.36"
  },
}, function(err, response, body) { 
  //here is your body 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One thing I do want to note for other people who read this. This solution worked, but I have run into the issues of getting caught in an event loop as well as having to release event listeners.

Answer (score 2):

The [Request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) follows HTTP 3xx redirects by default but the URL you are using is returning an HTTP 200 with a [META REFRESH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) style of redirect. I'm not sure if Request supports this particular style of redirect so you may need to parse the response and follow it manually.

```
GET http://t.co/gJ74UfmH4i HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
cache-control: private,max-age=300
content-length: 208
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Fri, 28 Aug 2015 16:28:59 GMT
expires: Fri, 28 Aug 2015 16:33:59 GMT
server: tsa_b
set-cookie: muc=b0a729d6-9a30-466c-9cd9-57306369613f; Expires=Wed, 09 Aug 2017 16:28:59 GMT; Domain=t.co
x-connection-hash: 28133ba91da8c83d45afa434e12f8a72
x-response-time: 9
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

<noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://nyti.ms/1EmZJhP"></noscript><title>http://nyti.ms/1EmZJhP</title><script>window.opener = null; location.replace("http:\/\/nyti.ms\/1EmZJhP")</script>
```

One possible route to understanding the issue would be to use a function for followRedirect to see if you can find out where it's failing.

From the [README](https://github.com/request/request/blob/d0a9a6b1299bda84c6dcdaf7d8a3176d67c40e74/README.md):

`followRedirect` - follow HTTP 3xx responses as redirects (default: `true`). **This property can also be implemented as function which gets response object as a single argument and should return `true` if redirects should continue or `false` otherwise.**

Comment: I found that as well. What I did find in the documentation is that "followRedirect" accepts a function that has to return true. I am wondering if it can just return a truethy value. Maybe another request function.

Comment: ah, just saw this sorry.